# How do I dockerize my python executable file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, executable

Sort of new to docker environment and microservices and I want to dockerize my python executable file ( it is in .exe format) . Im looking at an ubuntu base image which takes cares of all my dependencies and has my source code in. But as I understand, Ubuntu does not support .exe applications. So how do I convert my application into an executable file format and then build a docker Image out of that?
Also, the way my application works is by providing input files so that the applications reads the data, transfroms it and puts the transformed data into a different file. However , these input files keep changing and my understanding is that docker images are immutable, I do not want to build a docker container every time I have to provide new input files.
Is there a way I can provide these files outside the container so that docker can pick the files up and write the output files in a folder outside the container?

Comment: I don't understand why you have made a (Windows?) `.exe` file out of Python to run it under Ubuntu? Why not just run the Python under Ubuntu? Or run the `.exe` in a Windows-y container?

Comment: My application is built on python and I was testing it locally in my windows host machine and everything works just fine. But I have a requirement to share this with others and problem with that is people having to install all the dependencies on their local system before using it. I also do not want to expose my source code

Answer (score 0):

Python is an cross-platform scripting language, so I think there's no need for you to run the packed executable in Docker. Try building a image for the script itself as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/)

Answer (score 0):

Linux in general does not natively handle .exe files (you'd need Wine or something similar for that) but provided your application does not container GUI and/or windows specific libraries you could easily use the python base image ([found here on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)) to create your own.

You are correct in stating the container itself should be immutable. If you want it to have access to files outside the container you can easily mount ([docker documentation on mount here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)) a directory on the docker host to check for its files.

Your situation has 1 caveat though. If it's indeed a script with a set end the container will run once and then quit. You'd have to start the container for each transformation. This is not unlike the way Docker was meant to be running (as in: run 1 process which might be infinite like a webserver, or finite like a script). If you run a webserver of some kind the container will keep running until that process is stopped. So that is something to keep in mind.

FWIW: As a last thought; do check if you really need to containise this. Putting stuff in a container is not always a great solution. If you can run it natively on your host that ***might*** be a better solution.

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear. The docker has to and will run forever ( I have a script inside my application which checks for input files in a specific folder every 2mins), so, the docker should and will run the whole time. But i'm not sure how the docker will communicate outside the container to check files in the local file system.

Comment: @rishabajain445: Like I mentioned in my post, you should only have code running in the container. Input and output files should never be stored inside the container. To circumvent this you could use mounts (I already provided the documentation link) and mount input and output folders as "shared drives" so they can be reached from the container.